# Update somar produto de uma tabela para outra tabela

Tags: sql

A query abaixo ela pega o produto da tabela VENDAS onde for igual o produto da tabela ESTOQUE e soma a quantidade, ocorre que essa query só funciona se tiver 1 linha de venda/produto, gostaria de fazer ela percorrer quantas linhas a VENDA tiver e não só uma, não sei se precisa usar while ou for.

```
UPDATE PRODUTOS  SET ESTOQUE = ESTOQUE +  ( SELECT QUANTIDADE FROM VENDAS WHERE CODIGO=' " + Convert.ToInt32(codigoTextBox.Text) + " ' ) WHERE  Codigo = ( SELECT CodigoProduto FROM VENDAS WHERE CODIGO= ' " + Convert.ToInt32(codigoTextBox.Text) + "' )";
```

Poderiam me ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Edite o seu código de modo a colocar o código todo no formato de código. Pode selecionar o código e clicar na opção { }

Comment: o problema de "só funciona com uma linha" poderia resolver colocando um sum na sub-consulta: `SELECT sum(QUANTIDADE) FROM VENDAS WHERE CODIGO...` porém tem que ver  o que significa cada "codigo" desse aí, a segunda sub-query pode ser melhorada, mas tem que saber qual a lógica

Answer (score 0):

Por favor, tente dessa forma e veja se resolve pra você:

```
UPDATE PRODUTOS
SET ESTOQUE = ESTOQUE + V.QUANTIDADE
FROM PRODUTOS P
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CodigoProduto, SUM(QUANTIDADE) AS QUANTIDADE
    FROM VENDAS GROUP BY CodigoProduto) as V ON V.CodigoProduto = P.CodigoProduto
WHERE V.CodigoProduto = ' " + Convert.ToInt32(codigoTextBox.Text) + " ';
```

Comment: Obrigado @NDelavi, deu certo só fiz umas alterações abaixo e funcionou. `UPDATE PRODUTOS
SET ESTOQUE = ESTOQUE + V.QUANTIDADE
FROM PRODUTOS P
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CODIGO,CodigoProduto, SUM(QUANTIDADE) AS QUANTIDADE
    FROM VENDAS   GROUP BY CODIGO,CodigoProduto) as V ON V.CodigoProduto = P.Codigo
WHERE V.CODIGO = 382`